# Python - Pass a range of float (without step) as an argument of a function

Tags: python, function, arguments, range, keyword-argument

I created a function and I would like to be able to call it with a set of keyworded-parameters that I call `**criterias`:

```
def actionBasedOnParameters(**criterias):
    # my code
```

Inside this set of parameters one of them will be called 'SumInc' and I would like to pass a range to it. The range will be of the form of [1:15] or [1:] or [:15]. Something that will essentially let me check whether a variable in my code is greater than a certain boundary or lower than another boundary or both.
In the same way, as these lines of codes do:

```
In [188]: 1 <= 15.98877 <= 15
Out[188]: False

In [188]: 1 <= 15.98877 
Out[188]: True

In [188]: 15.98877 <= 15
Out[188]: False
```

But I am looking for a neater way to pass both boundaries without having to create a parameter for each and many if conditions to get things done.

Something that would look like this:

```
In [189]: criterias = dict(SumInc=[:15])

def actionBasedOnParameters(**criterias):
    if criterias['SumInc'] is not None:
        if my_variable is in criterias['SumInc']:
            #action1
        else:
            #action2
```

Is there something of this kind existing?

Thanks for your tips,

Comment: You could pass a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object.

Comment: How would I then check that my variable is within that slice? Especially if there is only one boundary. Lets assume I set it as criterias = dict(SumInc=slice(None,15))

Comment: You can access the `start` and `stop` attributes and decide what comparison to do based on the boundaries provided.

Comment: Ok, But how do I handle the None boundaries? I get an "unorderable types: NoneType() <= int()" error when I try: criterias['SumInc'].start <= 12 <= criterias['SumInc'].stop

Comment: Based on akarilimano's answer: `start = criterias["SumInc"].start or float("-inf")`

Comment: Great thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
criterias = dict(SumInc=(1,15))

def actionBasedOnParameters(**criterias):
    if 'SumInc' in criterias:
        lower, upper = criterias['SumInc']
        if lower <= my_variable <= upper:
            #action1
        else:
            #action2

infinity = float('inf')
actionBasedOnParameters(SumInc=(1, 15))
actionBasedOnParameters(SumInc=(-infinity, 15))
actionBasedOnParameters(SumInc=(1, infinity))
```

Also, you'd better use `'SumInc' in criterias` instead of `criterias['SumInc'] is not None` because in your case if there is no `'SumInc'` it will raise you a `KeyError` exception.